# Group Mongo documents by id and get the latest document by timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Imagine we have the following set of documents stored in mongodb:

```
{ "fooId" : "1", "status" : "A", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "1", "status" : "B", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "1", "status" : "C", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "2", "status" : "A", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "2", "status" : "B", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "3", "status" : "A", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "3", "status" : "B", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "3", "status" : "C", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "3", "status" : "D", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
```

I'd like to get the latest status for each fooId based on timestamp. Therefore, my return would look like:

```
{ "fooId" : "1", "status" : "C", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "2", "status" : "B", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
{ "fooId" : "3", "status" : "D", "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000Z") "otherInfo" : "BAR", ... }
```

I've been trying to go about this by using aggregation using the `group` operator, but the part I'm wondering is there an easy way to get the whole document back from an aggregation so it looks the same as if I had used a find query? It seems you have to specify all the fields when you group, and that doesn't seem extensible if documents can have optional fields on them that may be unknown to me. The current query I have looks like this:

```html
db.collectionName.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$fooId",
           timestamp: { $last: "$timestamp" },
           status: { "$last": "$status" },
           otherInfo: { "$last": "$otherInfo" },
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: You are doing it the correct way already. Sure you can use [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) and just put the whole document in a single property, but that is not the same structure, now is it? If you are so worried about "typing out" every single field, then just *"generate the final `$group` pipeline statement in code"*. That a very simple thing to so, and all MongoDB queries and aggregation pipeline statements are just "data structures" afterall.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing and aggregation, you need to do similar to SQL , which mean specify the aggregation operation per column, the only option you have is use the `$$ROOT` operator

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [
    { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$fooId",
           timestamp: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
         }
     }
   ]
);
```

But that will change the output a little bit

```
{ "_id" : "1", "timestamp" : { "_id" : ObjectId("570e6be3e81c8b195818e7fa"), 
  "fooId" : "1", "status" : "A", "timestamp" :ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"), 
  "otherInfo" : "BAR" } }
```

If you want to return the original document format, you probably need a $project stage after that

Comment: If there is a way to do it without aggregation, I'd definitely be interested in seeing that. The output using $$ROOT is definitely undesired, and using $project still will preserve the name of the field you used $ROOT on. I'd really like it if one could make the output look as though you had done a normal query.

Comment: @Shark Aggregation is your best bet here. Also as I mentioned in my answer you can add another `$group` stage to the pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) system variable with the [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator to return the last document.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([      
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },     
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$fooId",   
        "last_doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" } 
    }}
])
```

Of course this will the last document for each group as a value of a field.

```
{
        "_id" : "2",
        "doc" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("570e6df92f5bb4fcc8bb177e"),
                "fooId" : "2",
                "status" : "B",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00Z")
        }
}
```

---

If you are not happy with that output then your best bet will be to  add another `$group` stage to the pipeline when you simply return an array of those documents using the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([      
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": 1 } },     
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$fooId",   
        "last_doc": { "$last": "$$ROOT" } 
    }},
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "result": { "$push": "$last_doc" } 
    }}

])
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no direct way to bring back original documents and I don't see any value, but try following aggregation query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$sort: {fooId:1, timestamp: -1}},
   {$group:{_id:"$fooId", doc:{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
   {$project:{_id:0, doc:["$doc"]}}
]).forEach(function(item){

  printjson(item.doc[0]);

});
```

This query will emit:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e76d5e94e6584078f02c4"), 
    "fooId" : "2", 
    "status" : "B", 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "otherInfo" : "BAR"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e76d5e94e6584078f02c8"), 
    "fooId" : "3", 
    "status" : "D", 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "otherInfo" : "BAR"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570e76d5e94e6584078f02c2"), 
    "fooId" : "1", 
    "status" : "C", 
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "otherInfo" : "BAR"
}
```

Comment: So in actuality, I'm using springframework for mongodb to do my queries in java. As of now, I have some mongotemplate find queries that map the resulting documents back to a collectionName.class object. I'd like to do something similar for the aggregation query without having to create another middle layer object that I'd then have to map to collectionName.class. It's the main reason I'm being picky about this particular thing