# Find latest record for based on multiple ID's using Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I have a collection in mongodb which has the following format:

```
{
   parentId: "12345akNu",
   createdAt: "2018-12-02",
   complete: false
}
```

I would like to find all most recent records for a set of parentId's which are not completed. I currently have this query to find all records, but I cannot figure out how to only get the latest records.

```
collection.find({ parentId: { $in: list_of_ids }, completed: false});
```

For a single records this is the case of using `findOne` with a sort on `{createdAt: -1}`, but I need to run this in one query for multiple records if possible.

**Update**

As this has been suggested to be closed I am updating and clarifying the query.

This is for a Meteor application which (on the client side) has a limited interface to the mongodb drivers, supporting only `find` and `findOne`. It would be ideal if this could be achieved with only those calls.

Comment: Try `collection.aggregate([
 { parentId: { $in: list_of_ids }, completed: false},
  {"$sort":{"createdAt":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$parentId",
    "first":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}
  }}
])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group Mongo documents by id and get the latest document by timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603622/group-mongo-documents-by-id-and-get-the-latest-document-by-timestamp)

Comment: I updated with some more context in this being part of a Meteor application where the aggregate function is not available client side.